# What is the purpose "Using" in serilog configuration in appsettings.json?

Tags: serilog, appsettings

I am confused about the purpose `Using` in this configuration.
Unfortunately the keyword "using" is a very common word, so googling gave no usable result:

a) When configuring with code, I see no analogous builder method in the samples, just the `.WriteTo()` methods

b) It is interesting, I even commented it out, still everything works (both the console, both the file).

Are not the two Name elements under the `WriteTo` element (namely `Console` and `File`) are the two sinks here? Maybe the `Using` is a namespace to look for the classes? (then why it works when commented out? and also this should mean that both Console sink and File sink is under the namespace Serilog.Sinks.Console)

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Debug",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\mylog.txt"
        //"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] [Req: {RequestInfo}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```